# How to border image to a specific height & width to an image ? HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have an image attached below for which I want to write css that will provide border to the image from left & bottom. I tried but my code is taking full border

This is the required output that I want.[image]

```css
img{
    border-top: 15px solid #faa633;
    border-right: 15px solid #faa633;
    border-left: 15px solid #faa633;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="height: 400px;width: 300px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep the border transparent and apply a gradient with a specific size:

```css
img {
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#faa633, #faa633) 
    bottom left/ /* position */
    50% 40% /* width height */
    border-box no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/150" >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. Can i get css links tutorials which you are refering. It will help me a lot

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using box-shadow if you want border in only two sides of the image.